# All continuous functions with inequalities involved.

Tags: functions, continuity

> Find all continuous functions $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying,
> $$f(3x) - f(x) \leq 8x^2 + 2x$$
> $$f(2x) - f(x) \geq 3x^2 + x$$

**What I Tried**: We can take $x \rightarrow 3x$ to get:
$$32x^2 + 4x + f(2x)\geq f(6x) \geq 27x^2+3x+f(3x)$$
But this dosen't give much.
Another thing I tried, we can add both the ineqs to get:
$$(f(3x) - f(x)) + (3x^2 + x) \leq (f(2x) - f(x)) + (8x^2 + 2x)$$
$$\implies f(3x) - f(2x) \leq 5x^2 + x$$
I could only reach till here, any other progress is welcome and will be helpful.

**Edit**: Removed a wrong assertion that I made previously about the value of $f(0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to exploit the continuity of $f$. For $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the second inequality gives $$\begin{align*}&f(x)-f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \geq \frac{3x^2}{4}+\frac{x}{2}, \\ &f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-f\left(\frac{x}{4}\right) \geq \frac{3x^2}{16}+\frac{x}{4}, \\ &f\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)-f\left(\frac{x}{8}\right) \geq \frac{3x^2}{64}+\frac{x}{8},\end{align*}$$ etc., so for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, by adding these inequalities (and induction), $$\begin{align*}f(x)-f\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right) &\geq 3x^2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^k+x\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k \\ &= \left(1-\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n\right)x^2+\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\right)x.\end{align*}$$ Now, letting $n \to \infty$ and using the continuity of $f$, we deduce $$f(x)-f(0) \geq (1-0)x^2+(1-0)x,$$ i.e. $f(x) \geq x^2+x+f(0)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. An entirely analogous argument using the first inequality similarly gives $f(x) \leq x^2+x+f(0)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so it follows that there is a single family of continuous functions satisfying the conditions of the problem, namely $f(x) = x^2+x+f(0)$, or in other words, $f(x) = x^2+x+k$ where $k$ is a real constant.

Comment: Almost correct, Just one Mistake, You assumed $f(0)=0$,Nowhere in the question it is mentioned that $f(0)=0$, So all functions of type $f(x)=x^2+x+k$ will satisfy the inequality

Comment: True - the OP said "putting $x = 0$ directly gives us $f(0) = 0$", but they seem to be mistaken there. Thanks for pointing this out - will edit my answer.

Comment: @Prasiortle ohh I am sorry I typoed and thought we would get $f(0)$ in the LHS of both the inequalities but we just get $0 = 0$, so yes, we can't comment on $f(0)$.

Comment: Indeed, that was precisely your mistake - you just get $0 \leq 0$ and $0 \geq 0$!